# I want to print the element of array inside nested objects

Tags: reactjs

[image: the api response]I am getting an api response as nested objects with keys(links, count and near-earth-objects).I have stored the near_earth_objects info in props.search. I want to print the information of asteroid inside the near-earth-objects.
// actions.js

```
export const fetchByDate= (startDate, endDate) => dispatch =>{
    fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/feed?start_date=2015-09-05&end_date=2015-09-09&api_key=rUMAsp8IhAlems93UacOKIslTV02425e5CbE8oub')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data =>{
        const d= {...data.near_earth_objects};
        return dispatch({
            type: actions.fetchByDates, data: d
        });
    });
}
```

//search.js

```
let item= [...Object.keys(this.props.search)
        .map(date => {
            return this.props.search[date].map(i =>)
        })];
```

console.log(item)
output:

```
(5) [Array(12), Array(4), Array(12), Array(11), Array(11)]
    0: (12) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
    1: Array(4)
    0: {links: {…}, id: "3727665", neo_reference_id: "3727665", name: "(2015 SC)", nasa_jpl_url: "http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/sbdb.cgi?sstr=3727665", …}
    1: {links: {…}, id: "2414286", neo_reference_id: "2414286", name: "414286 (2008 OC6)", nasa_jpl_url: "http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/sbdb.cgi?sstr=2414286", …}
    2: {links: {…}, id: "3838137", neo_reference_id: "3838137", name: "(2019 CB2)", nasa_jpl_url: "http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/sbdb.cgi?sstr=3838137", …}
    3: {links: {…}, id: "3725760", neo_reference_id: "3725760", name: "(2015 PK57)", nasa_jpl_url: "http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/sbdb.cgi?sstr=3725760", …}
    length: 4
    __proto__: Array(0)
    2: (12) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
    3: (11) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
    4: (11) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

i want to print the array elements(name and url of the asteroid)

Comment: Where to print and how do you want to print, can you please show the code of your try

Comment: @komal jituri what exactly you want ?

Comment: @komaljituri as i can se all the dates having array and what you want to show. can you share your code to understand.

Comment: @VahidAkhtar i have tried different code, inside those dates it has objects(0,1,2.....) and inside these i want the name,links, id etc

Comment: @komaljituri actually i want your requirement screenshot or component code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203168/discussion-between-komal-jituri-and-vahid-akhtar).